# Validar un formulario en Laravel sin que haga scroll

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Buenas tardes y espero que estéis tod@s bien. Tengo una página web que a mitad del scroll, tiene un apartado donde podemos dejar el número de teléfono para que nos llamen.
Estoy validando que el campo no este vacio y que además acepten la política de privacidad.

No tengo problemas con la validación, el problema es que del modo que lo estoy haciendo se recarga la página y me lleva al principio de la misma.

Pense en hacerlo en AJAX, pero mi intención es que si esta todo correcto llevarlo a una página de agradecimiento.

Ahora mismo lo estoy haciendo así:

```
<form action="{{ url('nosotros-llamamos') }}" method="get" class="form-inline col-12 formLlama">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="padding: 0px;">
     <input type="text" class="form-control inputLetter" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Introduce tu teléfono..." style="width: 100%;">
        @if ($errors->has('telefono'))
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
             {{ $errors->first('telefono') }}
          </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btnLlama"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></button>
    <div class="positionTerminos">
        <input name="chec" class="chzxc" type="checkbox" id="micheckbox334">
        <div class="labTerm">He leído y acepto la <a href="{{ route('app.politicaPrivacidad') }}" title="Política de Privacidad">Política de Privacidad</a></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

En mis rutas:

```
Route::get('/nosotros-llamamos', 'app@nosotrosLlamamos');
```

Y en mi controlador:

```
public function nosotrosLlamamos(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'telefono' => 'required'
        ], [
            'telefono.required' => 'Tienes que poner un número de teléfono'
        ]);
    }
```

Tenéis alguna idea de como poder hacer lo que busco? Gracias

---

**EDICIÓN, PROBANDO A HACERLO CON AJAX**

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline col-12 formLlama" id="llamamos">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="padding: 0px;">
       <input type="text" class="form-control inputLetter" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Introduce tu teléfono..." style="width: 100%;">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btnLlama"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></button>
   <div class="positionTerminos">
   <input name="aceptaPrivacidad" class="chzxc" type="checkbox" id="micheckbox334">
   <div class="labTerm">He leído y acepto la <a href="{{ route('app.politicaPrivacidad') }}" title="Política de Privacidad">Política de Privacidad</a></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

La ruta:

```
Route::post('/nosotros-llamamos', 'app@nosotrosLlamamos');
```

El controlador:

```
public function nosotrosLlamamos(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'telefono' => 'required',
            'aceptaPrivacidad' => 'accepted'
        ], [
            'telefono.required' => 'Tienes que poner un número de teléfono',
            'aceptaPrivacidad.accepted' => 'Tienes que aceptar la politica de privacidad'
        ]);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(['mensaje'=>'validacion correcta']);
        }
     }
```

Ahora si no relleno el campo o bien no marco el check, me devuelve esto en el Network de Chrome:

Error 422

Pero me muestra los errores en la consola.

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors: {telefono: ["Tienes que poner un número de teléfono"],…}
aceptaPrivacidad: ["Tienes que aceptar la politica de privacidad"]
telefono: ["Tienes que poner un número de teléfono"]
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

Pero ahora como muestro los errores en la vista? y como hago un redirect en el success?

Comment: Porque no en vez de hacer la validación en el controlador, haces la validación con este plugin (https://jqueryvalidation.org/) y si el formulario esta lleno y los términos aceptados haces un windows.location.href="" y lo envías a la página que necesites

Comment: Hola @JoséVásquez me parece interesante lo que comenta, pero queria intentar hacerlo de este modo sin utilizar librerias

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer, que tiene que ver el scroll aca? Quieres validar el formulario y redirigir a una nueva pagina?

Comment: Hola @JuanRivera , el formulario esta haciendo scroll en la página, como a mitad de la misma, quiero validar el formulario y si es correcto redirigir a una página de agradecimiento, el problema que si hay un campo si rellenar, la página se recarga y se pone al principio de la página, entonces tengo que bajar para ver el mensaje de error.

Comment: @Miguel en ese caso puedes validar con un `form`(como lo haces) y capturar el evento `submit` para poder enviarlo por `ajax`

Comment: Y al hacerlo por AJAX puedo hacer un redirect?? @JuanRivera

Comment: @Miguel si, pero no con ajax, sino con una funcion propia de js (`location.href`) como dice Jose Vasquez

Comment: Ahí si que me pillas, poner en el `success` de la respuesta del ajax hacer un redirect?

Comment: @Miguel correcto, o habra un inconveniente al hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que no, voy a probar a ver!, y puedo mostrar los errores del mismo modo?

Comment: @Miguel tienes 2 formas de hacer. La primera seria utilizar solo el atributo `required`, ya que esta dentro de un `form` y si agregas ese atributo, sera obligatorio llenarlo- Lo segundo es utilizar el `validate` de laravel, para mostrar el error, ya que como se va usar ajax, en la respuesta de la peticion aparecera el error, asi que de ahi nomas juegas para mostarle el error al usuario. Aunque te recomiendo la primera opcion, ya que si o si tendra que llenar los campos o sino no mandara la peticion

Comment: Necesito hacer la segunda opción, pero no se como devolver los errores de validación tal como hacia en mi pregunta, pero con un AJAX @JuanRivera

Comment: @Miguel en tal caso, el error que muestras agregalo como hidden para que cuando surga un error lo muestras. Le pasas el mensaje de error nomas

Comment: Vale voy hacer pruebas a ver que sucede, gracias!

Comment: Hola de nuevo @JuanRivera mira mi pregunta de nuevo que actualice cambios

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119562/discussion-between-juan-rivera-and-miguel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que te muestre un error en tu mensaje tendrias que cambiar tu div de error por lo siguiente

```
<div class="alert alert-danger invisible" role="alert" id="error-telefono"></div>
```

Como ves, estoy agregando un id para identificar el campo de error, despues en tu ajax agrega lo siguiente para mostrar ese mensaje:

```
error:function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    var fail_msg = jqXHR.responseJSON.errors;
    for (const campo in object) {
        $('#error-'+campo).removeClass('invisible');
        $('#error-'+campo).text(fail_msg[campo][0]);
    }
}
```

Y estoy recorriendo el JSON de `errors` para mostrar y asignar el mensaje

Por ultimo, para redirigir a otra pagina solo agrega en tu `success` `window.location.href` asi:

```
window.location.href = "http://.....";
```

**Referencia**

- AJAX ".error": https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- Redirigir: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location